# How do I change this code to work in GUI tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Basically, the user will input a phrase and the output will be the phrase censored. My original code is this:

```
for c in phrase:
if c!=' ':
    print('-', end = '')
else:
    print(' ', end = '')
```

The code prints '-' for every letter but makes sure it doesn't when it's a space. I can't seem to make it work in GUI. I also already made a code to ask the user what the phrase is:

```
def phrase():
    phrase=simpledialog.askstring('Word/Phrase','Enter word to be guessed')
btnw=Button(window,text='Enter phrase',command=phrase)
```

Am I in the right direction or is there another way to do this? Sorry if I didn't explain it clearly, I'm a newbie programmer. Thank you!

TDLR; The code works and produces the correct output in the IDE but I don't know how to show the output on the GUI itself

Comment: is it because of buffers? Try flush = True in print function.

Comment: I'm sorry what does that mean? :(

Comment: print( 'yourstring', end = ' ', flush = True). This will clear the buffer of output.

Comment: Oh well the code works in the IDE and it prints out the censored phrase but I don't how to make it print out on the GUI itself

Comment: printing on GUI? It is setting text probably, for which methods would be there already.

Comment: ***"I'm a newbie programmer"***: Take the tour [python_gui_programming](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm)

Comment: When you get the phrase using `askstring()`, you can then apply the conversion to the phrase and show the result using `Label`.

Comment: my question is how to do that :(

Answer (score 0):

Define a label to hold the result:

```
censored = Label(window, text='')
```

Then update `censored` after a phrase is input:

```
censored['text'] = ''.join(' ' if x == ' ' else '-' for x in phrase)
```